# What is the English equivalent for Russian idiom "jump into the last car of the departing train"?

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, russian

There is a saying in Russian

> To jump into the last car of the departing train

This basically means to use an opportunity at the last moment, to finally decide to do something right before it is too late.

Is there a similar idiom in English?

Comment: There's also the slightly different [making a final effort](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430267/expression-to-describe-making-a-final-effort), and a couple of questions about [the eleventh hour](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197558/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-eleventh-hour) and variants, if you prefer a noun phrase.

Comment: One not in the duplicate is [by the skin of one's teeth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+skin+of+one%27s+teeth).

Comment: The duplicate seems to refer to a situation where a decision is made [earlier] to act just before the deadline. This is about a situation where one makes the decision just in time ('to finally decide').

Comment: With the opposite meaning, there is the  idiom "to miss the boat" (i.e. to lose the chance or opportunity to do something).

Comment: Jump on the bandwagon.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate do not exhaust the possibilities so the question should not have been closed so precipitately.

Comment: I also feel none of the proposed duplicates combine the idea of something both happening at the last moment and being done right. VTR.

Comment: @Anton If the candidate duplicate is really a duplicate (!), correct practice is to give novel answers there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An expression to define that "very little span of time"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173333/an-expression-to-define-that-very-little-span-of-time): 'I am referring to the context where you miss or don't miss something by a very short time, like when you miss or succeed in taking a train or a flight by just a few minutes or even a few seconds. What are the common expressions or sayings that can be used in such cases?'

Answer (score 1):

This idiom may pertain here: **the last chance saloon**. It originally referred to a saloon in the American West at the end of the town, the last chance for a drink. The Oxford English Dictionary also gives this second figurative meaning ("[last chance saloon, n.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/387443)," def. 2):

> 2. figurative and in figurative contexts. A final opportunity or hope for success; the last refuge of the unsuccessful or desperate. Now chiefly British.
>
> 1947   Time 7 July 23/2   Paris had been the last chance for One Europe (a U.S. reporter had dubbed the Parrot Salon, where the Ministers met, the ‘Last Chance Saloon’).

Note that the idiom labels the opportunity itself, not the use of that opportunity to do something right. Someone has not necessarily used that opportunity successfully yet. They merely *can* do something right. This headline and subtitle capture that, as Mr. Trafford's physical therapy is framed here as the last chance for athletes to come back:

> Former American Football player has become "last chance saloon" for injured athletes. Professional sports stars including former Lionesses, Liverpool and Celtic academy prospects, MMA fighters and rugby players have turned to Tendai Trafford for kinetic therapy (*[The Mirror](https://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/other-sports/american-sports/former-american-football-player-become-29585380)*)

Answer (score 1):

You could describe this as doing something **in the nick of time.** [TfD defines this phrase as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+nick+of+time)

> At the last possible moment before a deadline or before something begins or ends; just in time.

Answer (score 1):

How about "a last ditch effort"?

> A last-ditch effort or attempt is one final, no-holds-barred, possibly
> desperate push to accomplish (or prevent) something. It’s a reference
> to the military tradition of defending your territory to the death,
> even when invaders have reached your very last trenches; the phrase
> die in the last ditch has been around since the early 18th century.][1](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?hspart=trp&hsimp=yhs-001&grd=1&type=Y167_F163_202037_051923&p=the%20saying%20%22a%20last%20ditch%20effort%22)